# Azure DevOps VssConnection - How to tell if the server is hosted or on premises?

Tags: c#, azure-devops-rest-api, azure-devops-extensions, azure-devops-server

Using `VssConnection` (or something else) is there a way to tell if the server being connected to is on premises or an hosted by Microsoft (i.e. Azure DevOps Service)? My research so far says that if the `ServerType` GUID is `{87966eaa-cb2a-443f-be3c-47bd3b5bf3cb}` then it is a on-premises instance but I can't find this documented anywhere.

In the previous version of APIs (SOAP based APIs) the `ServerCapabilities` enum as returned by an instance of `TfsTeamProjectCollection` used to be able to do this. The property 'IsHostedServer' on `TfsTeamProjectCollection` had this information which was actually returned from the server itself.

Is there a way to definitely tell this?

Comment: What wrong with check the URL? (if it containd "dev.azure.com" is Azure DevOps Service)

Comment: That is not scaleable. If Azure DevOps allows customized URLs for organizations, this approach will fail. Also the URLs can have a different format i.e. instead of dev.azure.com/org you can also use org.visualstudio.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update**:

I have tested on my side, you are correct that you can use `ServerType` property of VssConnection to tell whether the server is hosted or on premises. `87966eaa-cb2a-443f-be3c-47bd3b5bf3cb` is server, while `00025394-6065-48ca-87d9-7f5672854ef7` is service. Unfortunately, I don't find any documentation states this information. But from the test, the ServerType does give the server information.

---

Usually, we use the following code to connect to Azure DevOps Service/Server:

```
VssConnection connection = new VssConnection(new Uri(c_collectionUri), creds);
```

If you connect to Azure DevOps Service, you would define the `c_collectionUri` as below:

```
String c_collectionUri = "https://dev.azure.com/org";
```

And if you connect to Azure DevOps Server, you would define the `c_collectionUri` as below:

```
String c_collectionUri = "http://TFS:8080/tfs/defaultcollection";
```

Comment: Thanks but that is quite error prone and not scaleable. If Azure DevOps allows customized URLs for organizations, this approach will fail. Also the URLs can have a different format i.e. instead of dev.azure.com/org you can also use org.visualstudio.com. Finally there is no compulsion on hosted servers to use port 8080.

Comment: For Azure DevOps Service, you would only have two formats of the URL: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/release-notes/2018/sep-10-azure-devops-launch#administration. For Azure DevOps Server, you have to specify the team project collection. It's supposed to distinguish the service and server easily.

Comment: I have added more details on how this information could be ascertained in the SOAP based APIs available up until v15.0 of Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Client package. I am looking for a more concrete and longer term option than relying on URL structure.s

Comment: Thanks for your explanation. I now understand your question better. I have tested on my side, you are correct that you can use `ServerType` property in `VssConnection` to tell whether the server is hosted or on premises. `87966eaa-cb2a-443f-be3c-47bd3b5bf3cb` is server, while `00025394-6065-48ca-87d9-7f5672854ef7` is service.

Comment: Thanks Cece. Is this documented anywhere that you might know of?